# UltiSnips plugin does not working on MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

I installed UltiSnips plugin on MacVim using vundle. When I run :UltiSnipsEdit command, I got error below:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/arya/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
line    7:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 import vim
line    8:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 from UltiSnips import UltiSnips_Manager
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#Edit:
line    6:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:     py3 vim.command("let file = '%s'" % UltiSnips_Manager._file_to_edit(vim.eval("type"), vim.eval('a:bang')))
```

What might be the problem here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have python3(not python2) installed?
If not, you can easily install it with macports or homebrew.

edit1:
You can also check vim dynamic python support by `:echo has("python_dynamic")`. It should return 1.
And then add
set pythonthreehome=`your python3 home dir`